# NodeJS rest api which return response similar like Java Map e.g. Map<String,List<Class>>

Tags: node.js

I am having 2 tables **product_categories** and **product_sub_categories** and these table columns are as follows:
**product_categories:**
category_id category_name created_by created_date updated_by updated_date
**product_sub_categories:**
sub_category_id category_id sub_category_name created_by created_date updated_by updated_date

I am able to fetch product categories and sub_categories like:

```
//show all Category
route.get('/getAllCategory',(req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM product_categories";
  let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
  });
});
//show all SubCategory
route.get('/getAllSubCategory',(req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM product_sub_categories";
  let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
  });
});
```

**The response of getAllCategory:**

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "error": null,
    "response": [
        {
            "category_id": 1,
            "category_name": "Baby Care",
            "created_by": "admin",
            "created_date": "2020-05-31T09:39:06.000Z",
            "updated_by": "admin",
            "updated_date": "2020-05-31T09:39:06.000Z"
        },
        {
            "category_id": 2,
            "category_name": "Personal Care",
            "created_by": "admin",
            "created_date": "2020-05-31T09:43:09.000Z",
            "updated_by": "admin",
            "updated_date": "2020-05-31T09:43:09.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The response of getAllSubCategory:**

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "error": null,
    "response": [
        {
            "sub_category_id": 35,
            "category_id": 1,
            "sub_category_name": "Baby Food",
            "created_by": "admin",
            "created_date": "2020-06-09T16:54:15.000Z",
            "updated_by": "admin",
            "updated_date": "2020-06-09T16:54:15.000Z"
        },
        {
            "sub_category_id": 36,
            "category_id": 1,
            "sub_category_name": "Diapers &amp; Wipes",
            "created_by": "admin",
            "created_date": "2020-06-09T16:55:05.000Z",
            "updated_by": "admin",
            "updated_date": "2020-06-09T16:55:05.000Z"
        },
        {
            "sub_category_id": 27,
            "category_id": 2,
            "sub_category_name": "Skin Care",
            "created_by": "admin",
            "created_date": "2020-06-09T16:54:15.000Z",
            "updated_by": "admin",
            "updated_date": "2020-06-09T16:54:15.000Z"
        },
        {
            "sub_category_id": 28,
            "category_id": 2,
            "sub_category_name": "Hair Care",
            "created_by": "admin",
            "created_date": "2020-06-09T16:55:05.000Z",
            "updated_by": "admin",
            "updated_date": "2020-06-09T16:55:05.000Z"
        }       
    ]
}
```

But I want to merge these into one so that I can get response like:
 { "CategoryName1":[ listOfSubCategory_ofCategoryName1],
 "CategoryName2":[ listOfSubCategory_ofCategoryName2]}
 Sample Example:

```
{
    "Baby Care": [
        {
            "sub_category_id": "35",
            "sub_category_name": "Baby Food"
        },
        {
            "sub_category_id": "36",
            "sub_category_name": "Diapers &amp; Wipes"
        }
    ],
    "Personal Care": [
        {
            "sub_category_id": "27",
            "sub_category_name": "Skin Care"
        },
        {
            "sub_category_id": "28",
            "sub_category_name": "Hair Care"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show what you get with your actual code ? the content of the response

Comment: I updated my question with the response which I am getting from the current code.

Comment: I was getting error on finalResult = and on === category['category_id] so I added let=finalResult and modified === category['category_id] to === category['category_id'] now I am able to get output but it's not giving me SubCategories

Comment: yes sorry for the typos, corrected it. you say it's not giving you subcategories ?

Comment: yes getting only Category but not sub category

Comment: {
    "status": 200, "error": null, "response": [{ "Baby Care": [{"category_id": 1,                   "category_name": "Baby Care", "created_by": "admin", "created_date": "2020-05-31T09:39:06.000Z","updated_by": "admin", "updated_date": "2020-05-31T09:39:06.000Z"}] , { "Personal Care": [ { "category_id": 2,                  "category_name": "Personal Care", "created_by": "admin",
                    "created_date": "2020-05-31T09:43:09.000Z",
                    "updated_by": "admin",
                    "updated_date": "2020-05-31T09:43:09.000Z"
                } ]  }]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do better with one SQL request using a JOIN but if you want to stick to javascript here is a solution that may work :

```js
 //join categories and sub
route.get('/getCategoriesAndSub',(req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM product_categories";
  let query = conn.query(sql, (err, categories) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    // second query after the first
    let sql2 = "SELECT * FROM product_sub_categories";
    let query = conn.query(sql2, (err, subcats) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      // join the two datum
      let finalResult = categories.map( category => {
        let result = {}
        let subsOfThisCategory = subcats.filter(
          sub => sub['category_id'] === category['category_id']
        ) // get all subs related to this category
        result[category['category_name']] = subsOfThisCategory
        return result
      })
      res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": finalResult}));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: for sql2 if you change conn.query(sql, (err, subcats) =>  to conn.query(sql2, (err, subcats) =>  will work.This one is working just now I tested.

Comment: Please edit your answer  for typo so that I can accept it.